# process text info displayed by calling a terminal command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, terminal

When I run a terminal command it generates some text data in the terminal display. Suppose `blck` is some executable software tool installed on my desktop. I call this tool in the terminal on a file named `main.txt` in the current working directiory like this:-

```
$ blck -f main.txt
```

This prints some information immediately below the command call. I have to process this text to glean some information from it. I have the matlab code to process this text. But how to call this terminal command in Matlab and then transfer the resulting text information to Matlab variables. once I have the information displayed from the command call in Matlab then I can simply run my processing code on it.

Comment: Is `[~, cmdout] = system('blck -f main.txt');` what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, that's it!